# file -i returns wrong mime type for an mp3 with integrated image-thumbnail

Tags: linux, mime-types

If i enter

```
$ file -i music.mp3
```

it returns 
music.mp3: application/octet-stream; charset=binary

If i wipe all tags and image in this file it recognises MIME type correctly.

music.mp3: audio/mpeg; charset=binary

Is there any workaround or a bugfix? Is it possible to get correct data without modifying mp3 file?

```
$ file --version
file-5.03
magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic
```

Comment: Does wiping the tags and image in this file does it still play? Why do you need to worry about mime-types if it already plays ok? - Suggestion: Give us more details on how this file was created.

Comment: Yes. mp3-file without tags and album cover in it plays correctly. I need to regognise MIME-types because I use libmagic in my application to find mp3s. I don't know how files were created, but I should find a way to recognise any mp3 file correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem with the same version of `file` on Ubuntu 10.04. I modified `/etc/magic` and was able to get the MIME-type of my MP3s to display as `audio/mpeg`. Here are the lines I added:

```
# MPEG Layer 3 sound files
0       beshort     &0xffe0     audio/mpeg
!:mime  audio/mpeg
#MP3 with ID3 tag
0       string      ID3     audio/mpeg
!:mime  audio/mpeg
```

Taken from http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file/file-23/file/magic/magic.mime

I don't have much experience editing this "magic" directives, so I can't vouch for its effectiveness or security.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own rules to `/etc/magic` and `/etc/magic.mime`. See [`man 5 magic`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) and the contents of `/usr/share/misc/magic` (or similar) for inspiration.